# 17.10 empty HDD volume keeps clicking, works fine

Tags: format, drive, noise

I installed 17.10 on my nas on top on an SSD. I had a 4tb volume attached to which worked just fine (could browse the files etc). I formatted and partitioned the 4tb volume and now I can hear the drive going 'tsk tsk tsk' for lack of better explanation. Constantly. The drive is empty. There are no process running that could affect this drive (it's a clean install).

What's the correct way to trace what's causing it to chug?

Comment: just did a SMART self-assessment, disk is OK btw. No hw problem

Comment: Sounds like a bad hard drive... even though SMART looks OK. Unplug the data cable from the drive and see if it still tsk tsk tsk's... I'll bet it does.